# Copy column data without copying blank cells

Tags: excel, vba

I have 2 columns A and B

I want to copy the Column A data into Column B. There are few blank cells in A, but those blanks should not overwrite any data in column B. Only the cells which have data should be copied into B.

How can this be achieved in VBA?

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not a complete solution, but might give you some ideas:

```
Sub test()
    Dim R As Range
    Set R = Range("A:A").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, 23)
    R.Offset(0, 1).Value = R.Value
End Sub
```

If the data in column A include computed values, this might not work as intended.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have a conditional paste, you will need to loop here. Check each value in `Column A` and move the ***VALUE*** to `Column B` (*if-and-only-if `Column A` is not blank*)

```
Sub Jeeped()

Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Dim lr As Long, i

lr = ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To lr
    If ws.Range("A" & i) <> "" Then
        ws.Range("B" & i).Value = ws.Range("A" & i).Value
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```